# Remove all words after specific words including that specific words

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consists of sentences
I want to delete specific sentence in the dataframe if the sentence start with specific match that

```
df['data']=["First: This is the sentence good mode:one line","Second: This sentence is also good mode:one line","Third: this sentence is too long mode:two lines"]
```

I would like to remove the words starting from mode until the end including the mode.
Expected result

```
df['data']=["First: This is the sentence good","Second: This sentence is also good","Third: this sentence is too long"]
```

This is what I tried

```
unwanted_list=["mode: one line"]
df['data'].str.replace(unwanted_list, '', regex=True)
```

The result it remove one line but mode still there, I would like to remove mode: one line

expected output

```
df['data']=["First: This is the sentence good","Second: This sentence is also good ","Third: this sentence is too long"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with the `\s*\bmode:.*` regex.

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'\s*\bmode:.*', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
                                 data
0    First: This is the sentence good
1  Second: This sentence is also good
2    Third: this sentence is too long
```

Comment: Then use r'\s*\b[Mm]odel?:.*' or `r'\s*\bmodel?:.*'` with `case=False`.

Comment: can we use list of words to replace [Mm]odel , maybe the words would  change in the future. For flexibility